# Codeigniter dynamic routing with redirections

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

We need to have user-defineable URLs for for certain pages, for example

**controller/action/1/en** should be accessible from **/charlie/en** , where **charlie** is a custom string queried from the database.

The twist is that **/charlie** should be redirecting (301) to **/charlie/en** , where **en** is a custom string also queried from the database (i.e. **default_lang**).

Now, I am a sysadmin, not much of a coder and not familiar with the specifics of the codeigniter framework. I am not sure at this point if the custom URL routing and the redirection needs to be addressed as two separate problems and if any proposed solutions would be hackish or proper.

I was hoping for some ideas to point to the coder that will actually implement this, who thinks that it is not possible, and of course educate myself in the process.

With my limited and generic experience I would think it should be able to be done by extending the framework's routing class, however I have been unable to come up with a simple example.

Any advise from codeigniter's veterans is much appreciated.

Comment: Could you give a try to that [link](https://osvaldas.info/smart-database-driven-routing-in-codeigniter) ? If I understand well, it's represents well your problem. Note that it may be a quick and dirty solution, anyway states that it's possible to do routes with database. let me know.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I first found and proposed to the coder. It does address the first part of the problem and seems simple enough, however he has hit a dead-end with the redirects. That's why I decided to take a step back in the question, in case there is an approach that facilitates a solution to both.